# Taylor's Formula vs. Taylor's Inequality

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

In my calculus book, Essential Calculus, and in class we were using Taylor's formula to approximate the remainder in Taylor polynomials but I am having a bit of trouble understanding the intuition behind Taylor's formula and this 'z' value.

I have researched Taylor's formula and found out about Taylor's inequality.  Taylor's inequality is what is explained in the full edition of Stewart's books, Calculus 7th edition, and not Taylor's Formula, and I found this explanation of approximating remainders much more intuitive.  I have attached a small picture of the inequality. Also, I found that in Essential Calculus, the solutions to the exercises use Taylor's inequality as well.

[image]
[image]

What I get from Taylor's inequality and the examples that follow in the full book is that we are trying to maximize the 'nth + 1' derivative so that we can approximate the Remainder.  Is this reasoning correct?

Also, can someone help me explain the connection between the Taylor's inequality and Taylor's Formula?

Comment: You prove the inequality using the formula by using $f \le g \implies \int f \le \int g$.